# Yii Join with subquery, how to add params?

Tags: php, sql, yii

I have problem with getting Criteria params and table aliases to work. I need to get this query:

```
SELECT x.* FROM stl_election x
JOIN (SELECT agent_id, economy_id, MAX(outcome) max_outcome FROM stl_election WHERE economy_id = 92 AND agent_id = 6203 GROUP BY stl_election.economy_id) y
ON y.max_outcome-3 <= x.outcome
AND y.economy_id = x.economy_id
AND y.agent_id = x.agent_id
```

I have already made this:

```
$election = StlElection::model();
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select = "agent_id, economy_id, MAX(outcome) max_outcome";
        $criteria->condition = 'agent_id=:agent_id AND economy_id=:economy_id';
        $criteria->params = array(
            ':agent_id' => $agent->id,
            ':economy_id' => $this->economy->id
        );
        $criteria->group = 'stl_election.economy_id';


        $bestChoiceSql = $election->getCommandBuilder()->createFindCommand($election->getTableSchema(), $criteria)->getText();

        $criteria2 = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria2->join = '(' . $bestChoiceSql . ') y ON y.max_outcome-3 <= x.outcome
    AND y.economy_id = x.economy_id
AND y.agent_id = x.agent_id';
$criteria2->alias = 'x';

        $considerChoices = StlElection::model()->findAll($criteria2);
```

The output is:

```
Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`agent_id`, `t`.`party_id`, `t`.`economy_id`, `t`.`outcome` FROM `stl_election` `t` (SELECT agent_id, economy_id, MAX(outcome) max_outcome FROM `stl_election` `t` WHERE agent_id=:agent_id AND economy_id=:economy_id GROUP BY stl_election.economy_id) y ON y.max_outcome-3 <= x.outcome
AND y.economy_id = x.economy_id
AND y.agent_id = x.agent_id
```

Comment: Ok, I don't know why, but assigning params to $criteria2 is the solution for this. Still problem with aliases...

Comment: Could you check what "$this->economy->id" return? null or something?

Comment: I have logged it economy->id = 92 and agent->id = 6203. $criteria->params array also checked

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are looking at this from a very SQL point of view and not so much a Yii point of view.  I suggest that you learn model relations and the functions of CDbCriteria.

Note, for CDbCriteria, that if you are going to use the ->with() function, then be sure to include the ->together = true;

[Yii CDbCriteria Class Reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria)

The simple answer for you might be to just execute an SQL query, try this:

```
$query = "SELECT x.* FROM stl_election x
JOIN (SELECT agent_id, economy_id, MAX(outcome) max_outcome FROM stl_election WHERE economy_id = 92 AND agent_id = 6203 GROUP BY stl_election.economy_id) y
ON y.max_outcome-3 <= x.outcome
AND y.economy_id = x.economy_id
AND y.agent_id = x.agent_id";

$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested in answer:

```
$election = StlElection::model();
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select = "agent_id, economy_id, MAX(outcome) max_outcome";
        $criteria->condition = 'agent_id=:agent_id AND economy_id=:economy_id';
        $criteria->params = array(
            ':agent_id' => $agent->id,
            ':economy_id' => $this->economy->id
        );
        $criteria->group = 'stl_election.economy_id';


        $bestChoiceSql = $election->getCommandBuilder()->createFindCommand($election->getTableSchema(), $criteria)->getText();

        $criteria2 = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria2->join = 'JOIN (' . $bestChoiceSql . ') y ON y.max_outcome-3 <= x.outcome
    AND y.economy_id = x.economy_id
AND y.agent_id = x.agent_id';
$criteria2->alias = 'x';

        $considerChoices = StlElection::model()->findAll($criteria2);
```

I just missed 'JOIN' in ->join :/